# How to create a communication between a Spring boot restful api & a Flask restful api?

Tags: java, python

I am new to the python, and my app considers two modules, one is java based, & the other is python for machine learning.

I'm trying to make it possible to communicate between python & java using message queuing.

Usually i would use files & java Runtime class to run python scripts, but now I want to make things more fancy & professional.

Comment: There are several alternatives for that. You may use HTTP communication between services via a RESTful Api, message brokers like RabbitMQ, gRPC etc. All of them depends on you need.

Comment: Yeah, rabbitmq, how can I do that please?

Comment: What cloud service are you using? each of them has its messaging queue service. for instance, AWS comes with SQS and Google Cloud comes with Pub/Sub and there are others and there are many independent services like Kafka. I recommend that you focus you question more on your tech needs to you can get more help in the answers.